# Append the search result in the input search field vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here i have an @click event

```
<h2 @click="action(customer.id)">{{ customer.name }}</h2>
```

When any result is clicked append this result to the input. Any ideas ?

```
<input class="search" type="text" name="search" v-model="search"  placeholder="Search posts..."
       @focus="magic_flag = true">
<div v-if="magic_flag">
  <div class="post" v-for="customer in filteredCustomer">
    <h2 @click="action(customer.id)">{{ customer.name }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i append the clicked result from the search to the input?

js here updated:

```
methods: {
            action(item) {
                this.selected = item
                this.search = item.name
                this.magic_flag=false;
            }
        },
```

I display the rest of the content here updated:

```
<div v-if="selected">
                            <div class="post" v-for="customer in filteredCustomer">
                                <div v-if="customer  === selected">
                                    <h1>{{ customer.name }}</h1>
                                    <h1>{{ customer.id }}</h1>
                                    <h1>{{ customer.address }}</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: you need to populate the `this.search` inside `action` function. Pass customer as parameter to action and then  `this.search =customer.name`

Comment: I have updated my question i have the method, but i need to pass the clicked name to input search

Comment: Where is `this.selected` used? your v-model for input is `search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `customer.id` to the action method, you can pass `customer` object as parameter to action. 
You can do something like this.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      search: "",
      filteredCustomer:[{name:'test1',id:1},{name:'test2',id:2},{name:'test3',id:3}]
   },
   methods: {
      action (customer) {
       this.search=customer.name
       this.filteredCustomer=this.filteredCustomer.filter(o=> o.id!=customer.id)
      }
   }
    
});
```

```css
h2{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="app">    

  
  <input class="search" type="text" name="search" v-model="search"  placeholder="Search posts..."
      >
<div >
  <div class="post" v-for="customer in filteredCustomer">
    <h2 href @click="action(customer)">{{ customer.name }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
`

Comment: you must be using `toLowerCase` somewhere which is causing that error

Comment: Plus how can i remove the search from the list below just display the result on the input search

Comment: I got the name appended to the input thanks, just one more thing how can i remove it from the list below when appended, so i don't have it twice ?

Comment: You can add this `this.filteredCustomer=this.filteredCustomer.filter(o=> o.id!=customer.id)` to filter out whichever field you selected. I have updated the code

Comment: by append do you mean you are continuosly appending fields from list one by one?

Comment: How can i display the other content eg, customer.id customer.address, when i add `this.magic_flag=false;` wont let me show the rest of the content on click. I have another variable , selected with witch is show the rest of the content. Thank you!

Comment: where is this.magic_flag=false used? can you add relevant code as well to the question.

Comment: I have updated my question i have `this.selected = item` and another v-for loop to display the rest of the content when one name is clicked form the search 
`<div v-if="customer  === selected">`

Comment: This way i can show the rest of the content only when the search is on focus, but i need to display the rest of the content when i click one search result no matter if on focus or not

Comment: Okay i made it work, thank you a lot @Helping hand very helpful!

Comment: Glad it worked, did you remove v-if="customer==selected" for last issue to work?

Comment: nope i just removed `magic_flag` from the selected v-if i have it there by mistake, all working, because its completely different v-for. Thank you man!